# Android:fail Ecclipse when I click on layout tab

Tags: android, eclipse

When I create an android project in Eclipse (Helios) and open for example `main.xml` and click on layout view - program closes. If I start eclipse over again and try click in project view on `main.xml` it happens again.

Comment: Not really programming related, is it?  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: IIRC (read the documentation last night) Helios and ADT are not friends - rather like you and Nicole R.

Comment: Is Ecclipse crashing  only for android XML file?

Answer (score 1):

In the official installation instructions for Android, **they tell you *not* to use Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)**. Not that many people notice, three lines above that, they still tell you to use "Eclipse 3.4 and above", plus the link they still have there (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) points to the latest Eclipse, which is currently 3.6!

The real link is http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2

I urge you to do things correctly and reinstall Eclipse. You may have other problems if you keep 3.6. For instance, on some (but not all) computers, Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) may hang (or gets really slow) when doing auto-complete (it's looking for a non-existent folder).

Also, you won't be able to find Eclipse 3.5 Classic as the documentation still says, Eclipse Classic Galileo is no longer available on Eclipse.org, instead you should install Eclipse Galileo RCP 32-bit (Galileo doesn't have a good 64-bit version).

Just be sure to do a check for all updates, then install the ADT update site, restart eclipse, close all perspectives, reopen the Java perspective, and go to Windows > Preferences and click on 'android' on the left and make sure it found the old location of your android sdks.

Comment: I definitely agree here about 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I had 2 virtual machine- 1.5 and 1.6, in Java Settings tab of project settings I set the path to the new version and UI view has become operational.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the main.xml document in the project navigator and select open with a different method. Can you get Eclipse to open it any of the other built-in ditors?

Comment: good advice - xml files are interpreted by the ADT plug-in, it's also possible to edit them as text (though, this will make ADT less useful, the interpretations are quite helpful)

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal but it may allow him to get around the problem and get on the path to trouble shooting. Also eclipse may be trying to open it in a non-ADT editor. Anything is possible :)

Comment: That I am unsure of. I would do as others have suggested and revert Eclipse to the recommended version of 3.4